# PreventDefault with right click on an image

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to fire **document** right click event on an **image** ?

That's what I've done so far, I can only track right click event on my Image

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#myImage").mousedown(function (event) {
        if (event.which == 3) {
           //I need Some code to fire Document right click event (or maybe a different method)
        }
    });
</script>
```

Thanks for your help

Edit1:
What I want exactly is when i right on click on my image, i want to show a **menu**, not the image right click menu, but the document right click menu
It is like the image is not there or disabled, thanks again for your help :)

Edit2: 
What I did till now is disable right click event with preventDefault, now I need to display the menu:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
//Need to display the menu
}, false);
</script>
```

Edit3:
It worked thanks, I created my own menu, ofc it would have been great If I had the default menu but this one is perfect too :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).bind("contextmenu", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".custom-menu").toggle(100).
  css({
      top: event.pageY + "px",
      left: event.pageX + "px"
  });
    });
   //To hide the menu if left click event is fired
    $(document).bind("mousedown", function () {
        $(".custom-menu").hide(100);
    });
</script>
//New Menu
<ul class='custom-menu'>
  <a>Back</a><br />
  <a>Refresh</a><br />
  <a>Save</a><br />
</ul>
<style type="text/css">
.custom-menu {
  position: absolute;
  background-color:#EEE;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`event.which` is actually the wrong thing to check...

Use `event.button == 2`. See the [`MouseEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent.button) documentation.

Or use [`contextmenu` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/contextmenu), as @MarshallOfSound suggested (but subsequently removed as an answer), but be aware that it might also fire if the user invoked the `contextmenu` by another method than right-clicking, e.g. left-click + `CTRL` on OSX. And it is pretty recent HTML5 stuff, so it might not work with older browsers.

*Edit* After your edit it appears `contextmenu` might be better suited for your needs. Also, [`event.preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault) is your friend. ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help, i feel i am very close to the solution but I just donno how exactly

Comment: You'll have to do the menu yourself. There are tons of implementations for that, e.g. [`jquery.ui menu`](http://jqueryui.com/menu/). Or don't hide the default menu, but [add to it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/menuitem) instead.